# changing the color of a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to change the accordion based on clicking a link .It is working fine.The demo is shown in the following link http://jsfiddle.net/kufi/qp5Mg/

Now,I want to change the color of link that clicked(here from red to green).If I click a link it is changing from red to green .If i Click second link the first link remains in green only,It should be changed to red.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".accordion-opener").click(function(e) {
    $(".accordion-opener").removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('green');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Make use of the `addClass` and `removeClass`, Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/qp5Mg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
<style>
  .clicked{
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

And, in js:

```
$(".accordion-opener").click(function(){
  ...
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

**EDIT:** I've updated your fiddle with this code and is working OK: http://jsfiddle.net/qp5Mg/6/

Hope this helps. Cheers